# Space before BODY?

Tags: html, space

I can't seem to fix my issue, I have a space before my BODY for some reason.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' />
        <link rel='shortcut icon' href='img/favicon.ico' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div name='header_area'>
            <div class='wrapper'>
                <div class='content'>
                    <table class='header_table'>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='table_cell_left'>
                                <a href='index.php'><img src='img/logo.png' /></a>
                            </td>
                            <td class='table_cell_right'>
                                Derp
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div name='navigation'>
                    <ul class='nav'>
                        <li><a class='nav_link' href='index.php'>HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a class='nav_link' href='?action=forum'>FORUM</a></li>
                        <li><a class='nav_link' href='?action=server'>SERVER</a></li>
                        <li><a class='nav_link' href='?action=donate'>DONATE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div name='content_area'>
            <div class='wrapper'>
                <div class='content_area_box'>
                    test
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Stylesheet:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    width:100%;
    font-family:'Calibri';
    font-size:16px;
    background-image:url('img/pattern.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-color:#F0F2F3;
}
.wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:900px;
}
.content {
    margin:10px;
}
.header_table {
    width:100%;
    border:none;
    margin:30px auto;
}
.table_cell_left {
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.table_cell_right {
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.textbox {
    padding:2px;
    height:22px;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    color:#000000;
}
.button {
    cursor:pointer;
    height:22px;
    padding:2px 6px;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    color:#000000;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus {
    background-color:#99CCCC;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;
}
.link:link, .link:visited {
    color:#003399;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.link:hover, .link:active, .link:focus {
    color:#FF9933;
}
.nav {
    list-style-type:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
.nav li {
    float:left;
}
.nav_link:link, .nav_link:visited {
    float:left;
    border-right:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding:10px 25px;
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    -webkit-transition:background 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition:background 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;
}
.nav_link:hover, .nav_link:active, .nav_link:focus {
    background-color:#99CCCC;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    -webkit-transition:background 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition:background 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;
}
.content_area_box {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-left:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

Here is a picture of the result I get. I don't want it to have a space like this, I want it to start from the top. Also this happens in every browser I test with.

[image]

Comment: It's a margin of one of the lower elements, maybe "content". With Firebug that would be easy to check in your browser. Margins of elements inside other container elements may extend beyond the borders of that parent container.

Comment: I removed the .content from my stylesheet and I still get the same result? :/

Comment: Well, use Firefox and Firebug and check all elements in the HTML view, it highlights the padding and margin for the element under the cursor. Should only take 20 seconds to identify the offending element(s). Sure I could do it for you - but it's so much better to teach you how to fish rather than give the fish to you :)  *You can* figure this out yourself.

Comment: Your screenshot seems to be from JsFiddle (the `result` button). Could you please post that link?

Comment: @11684 http://jsfiddle.net/sFhht/

Answer (score 4):

Your

```
<table class="header_table">
```

has a margin of `30px`.
See

```
.header_table {
    width:100%;
    border:none;
    margin:30px auto;
}
```

Just remove this margin (or add a `margin-top:0;`) and all will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

> for the new people come here

```
    .header_table {
width:100%;
border:none;
margin:30px auto;}
```

The code above has a 30px top and bottom margin.
When an element has a margin and the parent element doesn't have content, its margin moves the parent margin.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).